# Can i name a C# namespace starting with a number?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm on a Mac and can't try it for myself right now.

For example, will this compile:

```
namespace 2something.something.else { }
```

Comment: thanks all, i will accept an answer as soon as the timeout expires

Comment: "timeout" expired over four years ago, LOL

Answer (score 26):

No, you can't.
A namespace name is an identifier and [the grammar for the first character of identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#identifiers) is:

```
identifier_start_character
    : letter_character
    | '_'
    ;
```

That means that the first character has to be an underscore or a letter (including letters in non-Latin scripts, such as Arabic or Chinese).

Comment: Arghhh. Too bad... My company's name starts with a number...

Answer (score 4):

You can't name a namespace starting with a number. You'll get a compiler error:

> Identifier expected.

Answer (score 2):

Nope you can't. You'll get `Identifier expected` error

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a number in front you can write it with words

```
TwoSomething.something.else { }
```