# ASP.NET Core MVC "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods" when creating a new class

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I created a new ASP.NET Core project, created a folder ViewModels and created an empty class inside:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace 10k.ViewModels
{
}
```

Right away I get a red squiggly line under namespace that says

```
"A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods".
```

Any idea why this might have happened??

Answer (score 0):

A namespace must start with a letter. If you change 10k to TenK, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your namespace - a namespace name can't start with a number in C#

You should get a compiler error if you try to run this.

[see here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6919229/4240221)

[unofficial C# 6 reference here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/basic-concepts.md#namespace-and-type-names)

Comment: Thanks! Made my day!